# Share Links on LinkedIn like Twitter

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

I need some links on my page to be shared on Facebook, Google Plus, LinkedIn and Twitter.
My links look something like this: http://www.example.com/subdomain?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3

Almost in all of the cases the shared URL looks like this: http://www.example.com/subdomain?key1=val1

All the keys and values after the first & are removed.
Example URL Generation Code

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=~$requestedUrl|escape:'url'`" title="Share this on Linkedin" target="_new" class="lin"></a>
```

This leads to the following:

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://www.example.com/subdomain?key1=val1&amp;key2=val2&amp;key3=val3" title="Share this on Linkedin" target="_new" class="lin"></a>
```

The `$requestedUrl` is sent from my PHP and will remain common to be shared across facebook, gplus, linkedin and twitter.

Comment: Then most likely you neglected to URL-encode the parameters you pass to whatever sharing functionality you use properly.

Comment: It changes all the & to &amp; when I use the rawurlencode function. So there is no difference - @CBroe

Comment: rawurlencode does not change `&` to `&amp;` – that would be encoding for the _HTML_ context. A URL is a totally different context.

Comment: Actually I'm using smarty flags to convert url to escape it as follows `$url|escape:'url'`. None of the flags seem to work. Referred from http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape.tpl

Comment: So what’s your actual code, and what does the rendered output look like?

Comment: @CBroe: added example code

Comment: That’s half of what I asked for.

Comment: Apologies... Now done @CBroe

Comment: So as I said before, that is _not_ URL-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Take a quick glance at your full URL...

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://www.example.com/subdomain?key1=val1&amp;key2=val2&amp;key3=val3" title="Share this on Linkedin" target="_new" class="lin"></a>
```

So, you *DID* escape the `&`!  ***BUT!***  You used HTML-escaping.  What you need is URL-escaping.  They are *very, very different.*

`&` turns into `&amp;` with HTML escaping.  But `&` turns into `%26` with URL-encoding.  So, your code should be...

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fsubdomain%3Fkey1%3Dval1%26key2%3Dval2%26key3%3Dval3" title="Share this on Linkedin" target="_new" class="lin"></a>
```

So, for example, I want to share this url: `http://www.revoltlib.com/?id=17`.  It has a `?` in it, too!  This is the share URL result...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.revoltlib.com%2F%3Fid%3D17
```

Works for me:

[image]

Wherever you are defining or getting `escape:'url'` from, it appears to be doing the incorrect type of escaping entirely.